# Download file with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, download

I'm trying to make a link which download a file from the public directory of the server (nodejs)

I'm using the angularjs routing, and when I put http://XX.XX.XX.XX/public/download/file.exe in the href attribute, It makes a 404 error.

Anybody knows how to do it ?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried with angular file saver? http://alferov.github.io/angular-file-saver/

Comment: write like this /download/file.exe ... you shouldnt put public folder in the url and also the ip

Comment: thank you araz, that was that simple